# Add layer from a folder to Map using JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I know you can add layers to map through map service using JavaScript API. Can we directly add layers (placed in a folder on ftp) to the map using JavaScript API. If so, can please explain it and provide me a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the API does not include tools which allow you to work with files in a folder or over FTP directly, but it might be helpful to check out the sample below.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html

this sample demonstrates how to visualize content from a zipped shapefile (by calling ArcGIS Online to generate a JSON feature collection).

that being said, if you need data to be available in a web application, you're usually best served by publishing it as some kind of supported 'service' instead.

Comment: Arcgis online is offline for us (:=(). I mean off the table. Can't we access shape file through .net framework?